# Meaning of 輪を作る in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

I came across this sentence:

だけど ─ ─ こうして**輪を作って**連むのは、それ以上の贅沢だと思う。

What does 輪を作って mean in the sentence? Surely it can't be "making a circle/ring"?

Comment: Any more context? Forming a circle of friends, or something similar, would seem like a good bet.

Comment: @user3856370 Sounds correct. So 輪 can mean "circle of friends>" The sentence before :
ほんの 半年 ほど 前 まで、 俺 は 孤独こそ が 贅沢 の 極み で ある と 考え て い た。

Comment: Adding some context would definitely help make this into a better question.